# How to navigate through pages iteratively if are scraping data page by page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, google-chrome-extension

I'm try to build a chrome extension to scrape data from linkedIn. I have problem navigating through pages since it has a pagination. It's only extracting from 1st page giving the resonpse.

When i tried to use just popup based code it is working. Now i'm trying to do it on content.js..Tha navigation to next page and perform scraping is not working.

content.js

```
const performExtraction = () => {
  const pageData = [];
  window.scroll(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
  const liElements = document.querySelectorAll(
    'ul.reusable-search__entity-result-list li.reusable-search__result-container'
  );

  for (let i = 0; i < liElements.length; i++) {
    const li = liElements[i];
    const anchor = li.querySelector('a.app-aware-link');
    const paragraph = li.querySelector('p.entity-result__content-summary');

    if (anchor && paragraph) {
      const profileUrl = anchor.href;
      const summary = paragraph.textContent.replace(/\s+/g, ' ').trim();
      pageData.push({ profileUrl, summary });
    }
  }

  return pageData;
};

const extractDataFromPage = (max, currentPage = 1, results = []) => {
  const pageData = performExtraction();
  results.push(...pageData);

  if (currentPage < max) {
    const nextButton = document.querySelector('button[aria-label="Next"]');
    if (nextButton) {
      nextButton.click();
      setTimeout(() => {
        extractDataFromPage(max, currentPage + 1, results);
      }, 2000);
    } else {
      /*eslint-disable no-undef */
      chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
        extractionComplete: true,
        data: results,
      });
    }
  } else {
    /*eslint-disable no-undef */
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
      extractionComplete: true,
      data: results,
    });
  }
};

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, sender, sendResponse) => {
  if (message.action === 'startExtraction') {
    console.log('Received startExtraction message:', message);
    const max = message.max;

    extractDataFromPage(max);
  }
});
```